# How to change the chip suggestions at the order preview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, actions-on-google

I want to create a chatbot with `Dialogflow` and `Google Assistant` along with `Google Transactions API` for enabling a user to order a chocolate box. For now my agent contains the following four intents:

- `Default Welcome Intent` (text response: Hello, do you want to buy a chocolate box?)
- `Default Fallback Intent`
- `Int1` (training phrase: Yes, I want, fulfilment: enabled webhook call)
- `Int2` (event: `actions_intent_TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` )

I am using `Dialogflow Json` instead of `Node.js` to connect my agent with Transactions API. I want to present the order preview (when ordering the chocolate box) by using the `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK` action of Google actions. For this reason, following Google docs, when `Int1` is triggered I am using a webhook which connect Google Assistant to the following python script (back-end):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import  requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",  methods=['POST'])
def index():

    data = request.get_json()    
    intent = data["queryResult"]["intent"]["displayName"]

    if (intent == 'Int1'):

        proposedOrder = order.proposed_order(location)

        return jsonify({
                    "fulfillmentText": "This is your order preview:",
                    "payload": {
                              "google": {
                                "expectUserResponse": True,
                                "isSsml": False,
                                "noInputPrompts": [],
                                "systemIntent": {
                                  "data": {
                                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
                                    "orderOptions": {
                                      "requestDeliveryAddress": True,
                                    },
                                    "paymentOptions": {
                                      "actionProvidedOptions": {
                                        "displayName": "VISA **** **** **** 3235",
                                        "paymentType": "PAYMENT_CARD"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    "proposedOrder": proposedOrder

                                  },
                                    "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION"
                                }
                              }
                    }
                    })


if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

where `proposed_order` is a function which I wrote in the module `order` which forms the order of the user in the required way specified by Google docs.

When `intent == 'Int1'` then this will present the order preview to the user (on mobile phone Google Assistant) which looks like this (the example is from Google docs):

[image]

**As you can see there are three chip suggestions at the bottom of the order preview: *Place order*, *Change payment method*, *Never mind*.**

**My question is the following: How can I (programmatically) edit these chip suggestions and add mine (e.g. add one chip suggestion *'Change number of items ordered'*?**

Comment: Within the platform's order form, you do not have additional control over what options the user sees. You'd want to have add an intermediary step to give them a pre-final check.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @NickFelker. Therefore, do you mean specifically that I cannot modify at all the chip suggestions of the order preview (actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK) and therefore I should simply check e..g the item of numbers indepedently of the order preview (actions.intent.TRANSACTION_REQUIREMENTS_CHECK) at an intermediate step?

Comment: P.S. My tone may look serious at my comment above but it is not..haha...I just want  to have a clear answer to this question so that I won't spend anymore time on it :)

Comment: Yes. The transactions intent is entirely handled by the platform. Anything custom you want to do will need to be done ahead of this intent.

Comment: Ok @Nick, thank you for your answer! You can write it down below and I can accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the platform's order form, you do not have additional control over what options the user sees. You'd want to have add an intermediary step of the conversation to give them a pre-final check before sending the transaction intent.